# JDA Discord Bot not recognizing user messages properly

Tags: java, discord, bots

Whenever a user in my discord sends a message, I try to log that message, however it thinks the message length is always zero. The one exception to this is that the bots own messages it detects perfectly fine.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    String message = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();

    System.out.println(message + " - " + message.length());
    if (!event.getAuthor().isBot()) {
        event.getMessage().reply("test").queue();
    }
}
```

The output of the above code in the terminal is as follows when I send a message of "hello":

```
 - 0
test - 4
```

As it can be seen, the contents and length of my "hello" message is not being recognized, but my bots reply of "test" is recognized perfectly fine. I am quite puzzled by this issue and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like there is something wrong with the format (from discord) and your ide cant show it. Try to use getContentDisplay() which is a formatted text instead of getContentRaw which will return a raw textual content

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the message content intent. This is explained in the [troubleshooting guide](https://jda.wiki/using-jda/troubleshooting/#cannot-get-message-content-attempting-to-access-message-content-without-gatewayintent).

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me

```
JDABuilder builder = JDABuilder.createDefault("asdfafdas");
builder.enableIntents(GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT);
```